# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ",": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I somehow cannot create a new table. I've checked my syntax and searched other people having the same error but I can't find what the error is.

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "food_database";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "food_table";
private static final String UID = "_id";
private static final String CALORIE_COLUMN = "Calorie";
private static final String FOOD_COLUMN = "Food";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CALORIE_COLUMN+" FLOAT , "+FOOD_COLUMN+" text not null);";
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;

private Context context;

public FoodHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    try {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("HEY","Error creating");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_1) called `FLOAT` in SQLite!

Just replace `Float` with `REAL`!